# How do I create an OpenGL 1.2 context in GLFW 3

Tags: c++, opengl, window, glfw, openglcontext

I want to create OpenGL 1.2 context, but I get this error: "Failed to open GLFW window".
When I create 3.3 or 4.3 context there is no problem. How can I create 1.2 context?

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 1);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

const GLFWvidmode * mode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
WindowWidth = mode->width;
WindowHeight = mode->height;
midWindowWidth = WindowWidth / 2;
midWindowHeight = WindowHeight / 2;



window = glfwCreateWindow(WindowWidth, WindowHeight, "Quadcopter Project", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), NULL);
if( window == NULL )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. \n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no profiles in OpenGL < 3.2. You cannot create a 1.2 core profile because there is no such thing.

You allso cannot directly force the driver to create a 1.2 context. The afunctionality to request a specific context version was introduced in 3.0. So basically, everything before 3.0 is just some legacy context. You can ask for 1.2, but it might give you a much higher (compatibility profile) context, depending on the platform and the drivers you try this on.

Comment: So my graphics card is Intel. It doesn't support 3.3 or 3.2. How can I run the code?

Comment: What code? YOu can just remove `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR`, `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` and `GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE` GLFW window hint settings altogether and will end up with the highest legacy profile it does support. However, if this is part of some GL program, it might still not run as it may rely on the existence of modern GL features. But I'm still confused as you say in your original post that you can create 3.3 or 4.3 core profile context with "no problem", and now you telling me that your GPU does not support them at all.

Comment: Also, are you sure that your graphics card does not support OpenGL 3? At very least it should support OpenGL 2.1, perhaps your graphics drivers are out of date?